# How to only view H2 tags in a table in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below JS that shows all H tags  but I only want to view H2 tags from the a Div tag to show in table on left handside

```
var Table = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var tocHtml = '';
        var newLine, el, title, link, headingCount;
        headingCount = 0;
        var pageContent = $('#content :header');
        if (pageContent.length === 0) {
            pageContent = $('#middleColumn :header');
        }
        pageContent.each(function () {
            el = $(this);
            if (el.parent().attr("id") != "divTitle" && el.parent().attr("id") != "Table") {
                title = el.text();
                el.prepend('<a name="' + headingCount + '"></a>');
                link = '#' + headingCount;
                newLine = '<div class="table-header-' + el[0].tagName + '">' + '<a href=\'' + link + '\'>' + title + '</a></div>';
                tocHtml += newLine;
                headingCount += 1;
            }
```

I only want to view H2 tags from the main Div

Answer (score 0):

To select only `h2` tags - change your "headers" selector 
*from*:

```
var pageContent = $('#content :header');
if (pageContent.length === 0) {
    pageContent = $('#middleColumn :header');
}
```

*to*:

```
var pageContent = $('#content h2');
if (pageContent.length === 0) {
    pageContent = $('#middleColumn h2');
}
```